# Open or run a VBA macro from Python in order to fix poisiting

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

```
Sub MoveAndSizeWithCells()
    Dim xPic As Picture
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
        Pic.Placement = MoveAndSize
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

this was the code that i wanted to execute on some of my worksheets but through python I am not able to do this . can anybody plzz help

Comment: Where is the python code you have tried?, it sounds like the code works fine, just not when using python to run it.

Comment: yes the code works abolutely fine in vba just the cruck was that i wanted to get it done through my python which doesnt seem to be happeninhg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505676/use-python-to-write-vba-script

Comment: can u plz help me fixig this issue . i am trying to get it done through above code